# Writing templated functions for Eigen and std::vectors

Tags: c++, eigen

I wish to write a templated function to accept both Eigen::VectorX* (float/int/double) and std::vector<*> (float/int/double) and "simple" int/float/double.

How do i declare the template? The following doesn't work.

```
// header.h

//std::vector function
template <typename T, typename A>
void do_something(std::vector<T, A> &stdvec)
{
    //do stuff with std::vector<T>
    //e.g. std::fill(stdvec.begin(),stdvec.end(),0);
}

//Eigen vector function
template <typename Derived>
void do_something(Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> &evec)
{
    //do stuff with Eigen::VectorX
    //e.g. evec.setZero()
}

//single value function
template <typename T>
void do_something(T &var)
{
    //do stuff with int/float/double
    //e.g. var = 0;
}
```

The rationale is to not write individual functions all the different combinations.

Comment: Thanks all who answered. All 3 answers are great.  ggael and user2658323 answer are very useful for templated functions doing mathematical operations on the container (Eigen/std::vector)

Comment: I accepted chtz answer because it is most applicable to what I need. (I am saving the variables via HDF5 to disk, so i need a way to handle saving std:vector, Eigen::VectorX and "simple" types.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Eigen::VectorX*` only inherits from `Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>`, so C++ will prefer the `do_something(T &var)` method. You can declare the Eigen variant of your function as:

```
template<typename Scalar>
void do_something(Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> &evec) { /*...*/}
```

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. Do you mind elaborating more why this is so?

Comment: @Ziyang I don't know the exact reason, but you can experience the same when you have a `class B` which inherits from `class A` and a function which is overloaded for `template<typename T>` and for `A`. If you pass an object of `B` to it, C++ will prefer the templated function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::enable_if` to enable the fully generic version for arithmetic types only:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,void>::type
do_something(T &var) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to write several functions (as you discovered), but to apply the scalar function (`void do_something(T &var)`) differently depending on the container:

#### Scalar:

```
do_something(var);
```

#### [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), do_something);
```

#### [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a23fc4bf97168dee2516f85edcfd4cfe7)

```
matrix.unaryExpr(do_something);
```